# skipping cells in excel whilst doing an average

Tags: excel, cells

so i need help with excel. I have data that i am trying to analyse and there is just too much so i am trying to cut it down. I am trying to get an average once per 5 cells. so i have

=SUM(AB2:AB6)/5

i want to use this formula for over 30,000 cells but i want to skip 4 cells each time. is there any way i can do this, like how you would drag the cursor down if you just wanted to continue but by missing 4 cells each time?

any help would be hugely appreciated,

Heather.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If this would be usable, but I would make another column only consisting of

```
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
.
.
```

this would be an indexing column. then another column will be the formula simply using IF. IF there is a 5, give me the average of the previous rows in the values column, if there is something else, give me nothig/zero. and this you can achieve just by drag/dropping. each fifth column will be a relevant average number. i hope this is what you needed...

Comment: Thank you soo much! I got sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check given row's number using `ROW(cell)` function and then just use modular division function `MOD(dividend, divisor)` dividend being row number and divisor being 5 (in this case) to check if it equals to some number between 0 and 4, and if it equals to that number then do average otherwise do nothing. Esentially it alllows to calculate average in every fifth cell  i.e.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(A1),5)=1,AVERAGE(A1:A5),"")
```

if you want to start printing from different cell just change MOD(ROW(A1),5)=***1*** (the number 1, between 0 and 4)

Comment: No idea what the heck happened with that comment!! Sorry. I got sorted anyway thanks